# How to use Element Visibility in GTM when elementID varying

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to get the  preview count using GTM in my Angular application.  properties are changing inside a loop like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let ad of advertisementsArray">
 <div id="ad.adid" class="card">
   <span class="tag">ad</span>
   <h5 class="card-header">{{ad.adtitle}}</h5>
   <img [src]="ad.imageLink" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
   <div class="card-body" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom"
      title="{{ad.addescription}}">
      <p class="card-text">{{ad.addescription}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can first  is the for a loop. Second  is the one which I need to get the count. But in GTM we need to add the element ID (*id*) to the following space.

So I need to know how can I fire the elements separately without giving a constant ID number?